# Accidentally sent request to delete Stackoverflow account

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I wanted to delete my Stack Exchange account and accidentally sent the delete request through Stack Overflow. Is there any way I can revoke this request?

I really do not want to lose the Stack Overflow account.

Edit: Or, is deleting my account/profile from one community only not doable?

Comment: IIRC, you should get an email with instructions, and there will be a way to cancel the deletion. Don't panic yet. (As for being related to programming, it shouldn't be on _this_ site. Meta Stack Exchange is for questions about the network as a whole, which this fits into. At worst, your question may be a duplicate, but that's not necessarily a terrible thing.)

Comment: 'Member since today' ... that was quick.

Comment: @MartinJames check SO profile. Member for 5 months

Comment: Regarding your edit, check out the [FAQ post for deletion.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) TL;DR, yes, you can delete your account on one community only.

Comment: If you mean [this account](http://stackexchange.com/users/9315420/anj), (also known as "network account"), you can't delete it, because it's not a real account, just a "collection" of all your accounts in Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 11):

Chances are you got sent into the fully automated system that never interacts with a human. In ~24 hours it's going to send you an email stating there's a link in your inbox that you need to click in order to verify your deletion request. Just ignore the email and, more important, *don't click the link* and nothing will happen to your profile.